# how google crawl last modified time in site map xml

Tags: php, xml, search-engine, sitemap

suppose my websites name is www.somewebsite.com

i have a php file in  www.somewebsite.com/sitemap.php, this php file will be executed by cron 
This php file will create a site map for my site www.somewebsite.com/sitemap.xml

```
<url>
  <loc>http://www.somewebsite.com/some_stupid_content</loc>
  <lastmod>2010-12-10</lastmod>
 </url>
```

In the above code u can see last modified time is **2010-12-10** , which is not true.

What my sitemap.php file is doing is that, it shows the last modified time of content.php file from my content management system (content.php is used to create all the content(**some_stupid_content**) in my site)

so the last modified time in my xml file is wrong.

Should i make **lastmod** as the time in which my cron execute (i know this time also can we wrong). My question is will it create some problem for google to crawl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make lastmod points the right last modifying time. Google bots does not consider that entry, they know how to crowl in a clever way.

But you can make a change to make the sitemap.xml to show right lastmod.

Answer (score 0):

The sitemap won't do you much good for Google sake even if you update it manually.  What really matters to Google is human understandable update of site content.  If you have that freshly update in your sitemap.php  You will be considered higher rank by Google